# Azure Service Fabric : Remoting Compression Formatter

Tags: compression, azure-service-fabric, remoting

It may be obvious but I cannot find anywhere a starter example about this. What I am trying to achieve it to "transparently" compress data between services remoting calls when required (ie if > 20k objects => use compression).

If my memory is good, I think that WCF Services using remoting could be configured to use a specific formatter (ie binary) or a custom one (compression !!!). Is it someway also the case with Service Fabric ?

It would definitely speed-up considerably my "batch" operations without changing all the interfaces for integrating this feature myself (which is not that hard in the end).

Any tip welcomed as searching the official MSDN doc returns 0 results!

Best!

Edit #1: Seems that Remoting v2 could provide a solution with custom serializer:

> Actor using Remoting V2 Stack
>
> With 2.8 nuget package, users can now use Remoting V2 stack, which is
>   more performant and provides features like custom Serialization.
>   Remoting V2 is not backward compatible with existing Remoting stack
>   (we are calling now it as V1 Remoting stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the Edit #1 with some subtlties for dynamically using compressed or uncompressed responses & requests.